# "[engine] standardhost[localhost]: MAPPING configuration error for request URI" and "No context configured to process this request"

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jboss

I am trying to run a system deployed on a linux machine - built over jboss. I have ran jboss services but it is constantly giving these two errors:

When I try to open home page: http://localhost/  - it gives following errors:

"[engine] standardhost[localhost]: MAPPING configuration error for request URI" and "No context configured to process this request"

Can you please guide what I need to do to see proper home page, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, I guess that someone is accessing a context for which there is no webapp.

Comment: What WOULD you expect to happen?

Comment: I have just clarified question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any webapp deployed to the ROOT context. If you are using JBoss 5, then there is an admin console at http://localhost:8080/admin-console/ (but this is a wild guess, you didn't say anything about the version you're using nor what you're looking for).